# Can I see what code allocated which objects in the heap timeline in Chrome?

Tags: garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

When inspecting a "heap timeline" in Chrome dev tools I can see what was allocated at which point in time but I can't see what code triggered that allocation. Am I missing something? Does this functionality even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap profiler has no such ability but we are going to implement this feature.